# Find out the id of the last element of the Entity Framework table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I do not understand how to find out the last id of the table created for the user link and note. Most likely, I'm trying to do the wrong way to implement this.

I would like help:

1. How to get the last id
2. How can you make it more convenient?

Code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AddToDoViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ToDo toDo = new ToDo { Name = model.Tittle, Body = model.Body };
        UserToDo userToDo = new UserToDo { UserEmail = User.Identity.Name, ToDoId = ?? };
        var _result = await db.ToDos.AddAsync(toDo);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

UserToDo

```
public class UserToDo
{
    [Key]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string ToDoId { get; set; }
}
```

ToDo

```
public class ToDo
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mention user link and note, but I see nothing about links or notes. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write it, it can be autoincremented, do:

```
public class ToDo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

than:

```
ToDo toDo = new ToDo { Name = model.Tittle, Body = model.Body };
var _result = await db.ToDos.AddAsync(toDo);
```

in `_result` you wil have your object with autogenerated id

Comment: could you explain what this attribute means?

Comment: That means that id for `ToDo` will be autogenerated by the database, so you don't need to generate it

Comment: Maybe I did not understand something, but I have a connection table - UserToDo. It has UserEmail and ToDoId. I create a note, then create a link in the UserToDo table, for this I need the Id of the newly created note

Comment: Understand, but that is not correct, you should create `UserToDo` object after you get `ToDo` from the db, than you will have autoincremented id. Just say `UserToDo userToDo = new UserToDo {UserEmail = User.Identity.Name, ToDoId = _result.id };`

Comment: So after `var _result = await db.ToDos.AddAsync(toDo);`say `User.Identity.Name, ToDoId = _result.id };`, that is it

Comment: he does not know what _result.id is

Comment: it is `_result.Id`, my bad, capital letter

Comment: Maybe it will do?
_result.Entity.Id

Comment: Just copy and paste: `_result.Id`